# "Could not resolve path error" in the jsonparse section in job run for Chainlink external adapter

Tags: chainlink

I have a job for an external adapter added to my local Chainlink node.
It errors out when I make an initial request.
My problem comes down to a syntax error or using the incorrect path. But I'm not aware of where to find out what the syntax should be.
Or am I getting the path wrong?

Below is my job definition.

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "f1latestresults"
contractAddress = "0x765aCc258f3a7b2D8d103D1A9310fc51b07D5425"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]

    fetch        [type=bridge name="raceresults" requestData="{\\"id\\":$(jobSpec.externalJobID),\\"data\\":{\\"position\\":\\"0\\"}}"]
    

    parse        [type=jsonparse **path="data,MRData,RaceTable,Races[0],Results[0],number"** data="$(fetch)"]

    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0x765aCc258f3a7b2D8d103D1A9310fc51b07D5425" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
externalJobID = "524e150a-b92b-48a3-b85b-abf7218d73f4"
```

This is a snippet of the data returned to the job.

```
{
    "MRData": {
        "xmlns": "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4",
        "series": "f1",
        "url": "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json",
        "limit": "30",
        "offset": "0",
        "total": "20",
                
        "RaceTable": {
            "season": "2021",
            "round": "17",
        
          "Races": [{
                "season": "2021",
                "round": "17",
                "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_United_States_Grand_Prix",
                "raceName": "United States Grand Prix",
                "Circuit": {
                    "circuitId": "americas",
                    "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_of_the_Americas",
                    "circuitName": "Circuit of the Americas",
                    "Location": {
                        "lat": "30.1328",
                        "long": "-97.6411",
                        "locality": "Austin",
                        "country": "USA"
                    }
                },
                "date": "2021-10-24",
                "time": "19:00:00Z",
        
                "Results": [{
                    "number": "33",
                    "position": "1",
                    "positionText": "1",
                    "points": "25",
                    "Driver": {
                        "driverId": "max_verstappen",
                        "permanentNumber": "33",
                        "code": "VER",
                        "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Verstappen",
                        "givenName": "Max",
                        "familyName": "Verstappen",
                        "dateOfBirth": "1997-09-30",
                        "nationality": "Dutch"
                    },
```

The full results can be found here.
`http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json`

Answer (score 3):

Can you try remove the square brackets and use commas. ie instead of

```
Races[0]
```

Try

```
Races,0
```

ie:

```
data,MRData,RaceTable,Races,0,Results,0,number
```

If that doesn't work, please post your entire JSON output

Comment: Thank you Harry, that's fixed it for me. The job now completes.